# Filter a dataframe by a given condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

So i have a dataframe that i wrote to a csv file that looks like this

```
Atrasos,Data
18,2019-08-24
22,2019-08-25
52,2019-09-21
31,2019-09-22
```

When the last day of the atual month is reached i want to filter that dataframe to grab the values since the first day of the actual month to the last day and return it to render a graph.

I created a list with 12 months, then i set the actualMonth to a variable and now i want to do the if condition that contains the filter.

```
def graphs():
   months = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
   now = datetime.now()
   actualMonth = now.month
   file = pd.read_csv('files/graphs/delayedData.csv')
   file['Data'] = pd.to_datetime(file['Data'])
   if actualMonth in months:
      #do the filter depending on the month we are
```

I searched but i couldnt find anything that would help ...

the expected output would be the dataframe with only the current month since day one to the end so then i can grab that dataframe and create a graph.
So for this month (August) should return like this

```
Atrasos,Data
18,2019-08-24
22,2019-08-25
```

and then i should be able to grab that data and build a graphic every month when the last day is reached.

Comment: Please, share the expected output

Comment: @AlexandreB. done that, please check

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.dt.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = file[file['Data'].dt.month == actualMonth]
#alternative
#df = file[file['Data'].dt.month == pd.datetime.now().month]
print (df)
   Atrasos       Data
0       18 2019-08-24
1       22 2019-08-25
```

Comment: thanks , it worked like you said and like @Preeti Singla said too.
should i use that if statment to check what month we are or i dont need that?

Comment: @BrunoTeixeira - If need check scalar number in another list like `if actualMonth in months:` it is good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import datetime;

today = str(datetime.date.today());
curr_month = int(today[5:7]);

file[file['Data'].dt.month==curr_month]
```